# Cannot find uv option in texture mapping in Blender 2.72

Tags: texturing, uv, particles

I want to add a world texture in Blender and choose its coordinate mapping to UV to create a particle system fade out effect when using an explosion modifier just as this dissolving tutorial does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD8qlNdEt6E. But when I tried to do this, I cannot find such an option (no "uv" in the option list):

[image]

Could anyone please tell me how I can do this? Appreciate for your kindly help~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, world has no vertices so it cannot have UVs.

Comment: you're right, I made a mistake that the texture should be created in material texture panel.